# Using tooltip for a v-list

Tags: vuetify.js

I have a v-list with text that is too long so I want to use v-tooltip so that when someone hovers on the text it shows the full string. Unfortunatly when I hover on one item it shows the tooltip for all items in the vlist.

```
<div class="productNameIncoming">
      <v-list v-for="nameIncoming in productNameIncoming" :key="nameIncoming">
        <v-tooltip v-model="show" right fixed>
          <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
            <p v-on="on">{{ nameIncoming }}</p>
          </template>
          <span>{{ nameIncoming }}</span>
        </v-tooltip>
      </v-list>
    </div>
```

Is this a limitation or am I doing it wrong?

Vuejs 2.6.11 and Vuetify 2.2.6

Answer (score 0):

My problem was v-model="show". I removed it and it worked.